# Composition of scalar and vector functions

Tags: functions, vectors, function-and-relation-composition

Let $g(x,y)$ be a scalar function and $G(x,y)=<A(x,y),B(x,y)>$ be a vector field in the $(x,y)$ plane.

My understanding is that the function composition

$$g\circ G=g(A(x,y),B(x,y))$$

but

$$G\circ g$$ is undefined/does not make sense.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.  Perhaps specifying the domain and target of each function will help clear up any doubts.

$$g: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R \\ G: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$$

Therefore
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    \Bbb R^2 @>G>> \Bbb R^2 @>g>> \Bbb R\\
    @. \large\searrow @. \large\nearrow \\
     @. \stackrel{\large\longrightarrow}{g\circ G}
\end{CD}$$
makes sense while trying to go the other way wouldn't.  The problem with $G\circ g$ is that $g$ "outputs" a scalar where $G$ expects a vector "input".